# Когда не нравится(,) как разговаривает твоя дочь. Нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, как

Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении?

**Когда не нравится(?) как разговаривает твоя дочь.**

Comment: А какое это предложение - простое или сложное? В зависимости от этого и знаки препинания.

Comment: Это вопрос? _Когда не нравится, как разговаривает твоя дочь?_ Звучит странно. Очень хочется добавить дополнение "тебе". _Когда тебе не нравится, как разговаривает твоя дочь?_

Если это не вопрос, то здесь и вовсе упущена целая часть сложного предложения. _Когда_ - союз подчинения; требуется главная часть. _Когда не нравится, как разговаривает твоя дочь, ты её игнорируешь._

Comment: Всё тут нормально звучит. Хотя необходим контекст. Тогда будет намного понятней. Но такое предложение тоже имеет право на существование.

Comment: Нужно вопрос закрыть, потому что эта грамматическая структура не может быть опознана без контекста. Уважаемые модераторы, обратите внимание.

Answer (score 2):

Это предложение из учебника по русскому языку для 9 класса. Предложение сложное, т.к. две основы: не нравится и разговаривает дочь. 1-е простое предложение односоставное,безличное (материал 8 класса), 2-е предложение двусоставное. Данное сложное предложение союзное, сложноподчиненное. Не нравится что? Как разговаривает дочь. Придаточное изъяснительное. Между главным и придаточным запятая обязательно ставится.

Comment: Вот хорошее предложение, могу рекомендовать для учебника 9 класса: "Мне не нравится, как разговаривает моя дочь". Здесь всё на месте. А  заданное предложение никуда не годится. Мне не нравится, что обе его части начинаются с подчинительного союза.